# Where in Cyprus is this church located?

Tags: identify-this, cyprus

Found this screenshot of a church in EU Cyprus, but can't seem to find out where it is.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That'd be the church in Pachyammos, Cyprus - Agios Raphael.

Example stock photo: https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-church-in-pachyammos-cyprus-53616402.html

[Google Maps Link](https://www.google.com/maps/uv?hl=en&pb=!1s0x14e76382f87171fb:0x66fea4a67e97f170!2m22!2m2!1i80!2i80!3m1!2i20!16m16!1b1!2m2!1m1!1e1!2m2!1m1!1e3!2m2!1m1!1e5!2m2!1m1!1e4!2m2!1m1!1e6!3m1!7e115!4shttps://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipPdppscN28ULu3YmT1UtmIo8F0FrfuKspHcZvrS%3Dw240-h160-k-no!5sPachyammos%20church%20-%20Google%20Search&imagekey=!1e10!2sAF1QipPdppscN28ULu3YmT1UtmIo8F0FrfuKspHcZvrS&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjKg9iQq4bbAhUBsJQKHVZGDOMQoioIfTAO)

And the church [on TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.com.au/Attraction_Review-g3349857-d8036888-Reviews-Church_of_St_Rafael-Pachyammos_Nicosia_District.html).